# Algorithm to generate random proportion whose sum equal 1 and sum-of-squares equal $x$?

Tags: probability, summation

I'm in need of a simple way to generate sets of proportions (i.e. $0 \leq p_i \leq 1$) whose sums equal to one ($\sum_i p_i=1$) and whose sums of squares equal to a specified value ($\sum_i p_i^2=x$). The length of the set would $N$ would also be known before hand.

I suspect in the extreme values of x the system is fully determined ($x=1/N \implies \forall i \quad p_i=1/N$), but I think there will be multiple solutions for most values of $x$.

So far, I managed to get an equation that summarizes both constraints but it I couldn't find a way to turn it into a function of $p_i$ to implement it in a computer language.

Starting from $\sum_i p_i=1$:

$$ (\sum_i p_i)^2 = 1 \implies \sum_i p_i^2 +\sum_i\sum_{j \neq i} p_ip_j =1 $$

Plugging in the the sum of squares constrain:

$$ x + \sum_i\sum_{j \neq i} p_ip_j =1 $$

But this is as far as I got. How to turn that into something programmable (using random numbers) is a little beyond me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've noticed, there is a solution if $1/N \leq x \leq 1$, although at those extremes, the solution consists of isolated point(s).

If $\frac{1}{N} < x \leq \frac{1}{N-1}$, the solution, as JonathanZ mentioned in the comments (now deleted), consists of an $(N-2)$-dimensional spherical manifold (the sphere normally embedded in $N-1$ dimensions), rotated to lie in the hyperplane where the coordinates sum to $1$. That is, if $N = 2$, this is two points ($S^0$); if $N = 3$, it is a circle ($S^1$); if $N = 4$, this is a sphere ($S^2$), and so on. Otherwise, if $\frac{1}{N-1} < x \leq 1$, the solution set is a subset of this sphere.

The above probably sounds a bit abstract, so let me suggest an algorithm, to be used provided $1/N < x < 1$. (If $x = 1/N$, simply choose $p_k = 1/N$ for all $k$. If $x = 1$, then pick an integer $k$ randomly between $1$ and $N$ inclusively, and let $p_k = 1, p_j = 0$ for $j \not= k$.)

- Let $r = \sqrt{x-1/N}$. This is the radius of the sphere.
- Generate a point on the sphere.

  - First, generate $N-1$ independent Gaussian variables $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_{N-1}$ with mean $0$ and variance $1$.
  - Next, compute $q_k = \frac{rv_k}{\sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2+\cdots+v_N^2}}$. These represent a point that is uniformly distributed on the sphere.
  - Finally, transform the $q_k$ as follows:

    - The first output coordinate is $p_1 = \frac{1}{N}+\frac{q_1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{q_2}{\sqrt{6}}+\frac{q_3}{\sqrt{12}}+\cdots+\frac{q_{N-1}}{\sqrt{N(N-1)}}$.
    - The second output coordinate is $p_2 = \frac{1}{N}-\frac{q_1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{q_2}{\sqrt{6}}+\frac{q_3}{\sqrt{12}}+\cdots+\frac{q_{N-1}}{\sqrt{N(N-1)}}$.
    - The third output coordinate is $p_3 = \frac{1}{N}-\frac{2q_2}{\sqrt{6}}+\frac{q_3}{\sqrt{12}}+\frac{q_4}{\sqrt{20}}\cdots+\frac{q_{N-1}}{\sqrt{N(N-1)}}$.
    - In general, the $k$th output coordinate is $p_k = \frac{1}{N}-\frac{(k-1)q_{k-1}}{\sqrt{k(k-1)}}+\sum_{j=k+1}^N \frac{q_{j-1}}{\sqrt{j(j-1)}}$.
    - Therefore, the $N$th output coordinate is $p_N = \frac{1}{N}-\frac{(N-1)q_{N-1}}{\sqrt{N(N-1)}}$.
- If all of the $p_k$ are non-negative, accept. Otherwise, reject and generate another point; repeat until the point is acceptable. *Note.* If $N$ is large and $x$ is significantly greater than $\frac{1}{N-1}$, you may have to reject a lot of points. I'm not sure there's a simple way of handling this. It's a consequence of the [concentration of measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_of_measure) in higher-dimensional spaces.

It can be seen fairly easily that the $p_k$ sum to $1$, as desired. It is more tedious to show that their squares sum to $x$, but that is also true. (I hope. I'm verifying that now; if I'm wrong, I'll come back and fix this!) This algorithm is designed to generate combinations of values that are uniformly drawn from the space of possible solutions. If that isn't important, there are almost surely easier ways of doing this.

---

In case you're wondering where those crazy coefficients come from: They stem from my lazy way of taking the $(N-2)$-sphere (the sphere normally embedded in $N-1$ dimensions) and transforming it to lie in the hyperplane $\sum_{k=1}^N p_k = 1$.

The way I did that was to generate a set of $N-1$ mutually orthogonal $N$-vectors that are also orthogonal to the vector $[1, 1, \ldots, 1]^\top$. The easiest way I came up with to do that was

$$
[1, -1, 0, 0, 0, \ldots, 0]^\top \\
[1, 1, -2, 0, 0, \ldots, 0]^\top \\
[1, 1, 1, -3, 0, \ldots, 0]^\top \\
\vdots \\
[1, 1, 1, \ldots, 1, N-1]^\top
$$

These are mutually orthogonal, but they're not orthonormal, so I divided the $k$th vector by $\sqrt{k(k+1)}$. These were then used as the basis vectors to map the normalized $q_k$ to the $p_k$, and then we add $1/N$ to each $p_k$; otherwise, they would all lie in the hyperplane $\sum_{k=1}^N p_k = 0$, not $1$.

There's probably a much saner and more elegant way to do this with a [Householder transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation), but as I say, I'm too lazy to figure out which matrix it is.

Comment: This is glorious, thank you very much. I will start implementing it to validate that its square sum also sum to 1.

Comment: @JMenezes: The squares should sum to $x$, yes?

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry

Comment: @JMenezes: Python code (crude, but works) available on request.

Answer (score 1):

A different method to consider is:

1. Generate $U_1, \dots, U_{n-1}$ uniformly and independently from $U(0, 1)$.
2. Compute the order statistics $U_{(1)}, \dots, U_{(n-1)}$, and set $U_{(0)} := 0$ and $U_{(n)} := 1$.
3. For $k = 0, \dots, n-1$, define $X_k(s) := U_{(k+1)}^s - U_{(k)}^s.$ Then $X_0(s) + \cdots + X_{n-1}(s) = 1$.
4. Select $s$, if possible, so that $X_0^2(s) + \cdots + X_{n-1}^2(s) = x$ and return $X_0(s), \dots, X_{n-1}(s)$, otherwise repeat at step 1.

This is pretty straightforward to implement. For example, for $n=4$ and a target $x = 1/2$ the following were generated; bisection was used to select $s$.

```
[0.05653939687723922, 0.1144079674523669, 0.14990485814385168, 0.6791477775265422]
[0.25714634326221303, 0.012377144142809604, 0.07634161891333219, 0.6541348936816451]
[0.010316851634936052, 0.022499353274304093, 0.35776734310043806, 0.6094164519903218]
[0.017220358022991784, 0.024062849215038918, 0.33872888612448054, 0.6199879066374887]
[0.0015098866537681206, 0.011954804012041177, 0.4119373705918722, 0.5745979387423186]
```

Comment: Intriguing!  Can you elaborate on why this has the right distribution on output values?  (i.e., a uniform distribution over the set of $n$-tuples that satisfy the constraints in the question)

Comment: @D.W.: It's not clear that the OP needs that. I put it in my answer, but I'm not sure that an answer needs that in order to be acceptable.

Comment: Question for this answer: How is $s$ selected in step $4$? Do we do some iterative guessing?

Comment: For the example I used simple bisection for finding $s$, starting with $s_{\text{left}} = 0$ and $s_{\text{right}} = 20$. It was a very simple implementation that could be made more sophisticated.

Comment: @D.W., I don’t know in what sense these would be uniform over, say, the convex set $p_0+\cdots+p_{n-1} =1$, $p_k\geq 0$ if that’s what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The gold standard would be to uniformly sample the entire space of permitted values, but I get the feeling that that's not of interest to you.

Have you thought about generating $N-2$ of your $p_i$'s randomly (in a sensible range) and then plugging those values into your constraints will give you two equations in two unknowns, where the "two unknowns" are the last two $p_i$ values?

The only slightly tricky part is figuring out what the "sensible range" is, and what kind of random distribution you should use. Also, depending on your "sum of squares" value, you could end up in a situation where the equations for the last two values don't have (real) solutions. Is it okay in your situation to just throw those away and try again?

Overall, I think a strategy like this would never yield permitted extreme values, but would be simple to implement.

Comment: I don't think this gives the proper distribution on the resulting values (it doesn't give a uniform distribution on points that satisfy the constraints), because some settings for the first $N-2$ values lead to no solutions to the equations.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry if it wasn't clear. My suggested method in no way achieves uniformity. I just wanted to nod towards what I thought was the ideal mathematical goal as I moved far away from it.